# please tell me abaut its grade of this hadith

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Narrated Mu’adh ibn Jabal:
>
> The Prophet (peace_be_upon_him) said: The flourishing state of Jerusalem will be when Yathrib is in ruins, the **strong text**ruined state of Yathrib will be when the great war comes, the outbreak of the great war will be at the conquest of Constantinople and the conquest of **Constantinople when the Dajjal (Antichrist) comes forth. He (the Prophet) struck his thigh or his shoulder with his hand and said: This is as true as you are here or as you are** sitting (meaning Mu’adh ibn Jabal).

[Sunan Abu-Dawud, Battles (Kitab Al-Malahim), Book 37, Number 4281](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4294))"

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. Please note that this hadith has been qualified at sunnah.com. If that is sufficient for you please consider closing your question else evaluate it asking for details!